# Connect pgAdmin to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to connect pgAdmin 4 v4.17 to my PostgreSQL v12.1 that is running on a Debian v9 Stretch server.

I got the error `could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)`

I already tried:

run pgAdmin as admnistrator;

set to `listen_addresses = '*'` ;

Add the line `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`;

restarted the server;

Use SSH Tunnel with PuTTY;

Using PuTTY i can access to PostgreSQL normally and execute commands, but pgAdmin doesn't connect, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have the port 5432 open? Also is pgadmin in the same server as the postgresql server?

Comment: Hello Diogo! pgAdmin is in my local machine, postgre is running on a server in other machine, but both are in the same network. All ports are open to internal connections

Comment: Have you tried to replace `listen_addresses = '*'` with your local IP?`

Comment: Also can you run the following in your postgresql server? `netstat -nplt | grep 5432` and share the output?

Comment: Hello Diogo, i've tried to run the netstat command but nothing happened

Comment: Do you have `net-tools` installed? if not first run `apt-get install net-tools` and only then the netstat command